# Laravel handling CORS Options requests

Tags: laravel, cors

I am trying to make a small API that I could get an option request without a failure or error.
I made this middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->method() === 'OPTIONS') {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=>'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
        ];
        return (new Response(' ', 200))
            ->withHeaders($headers);
    }
    else {
        return $next($request);
    };
}
```

My `web.php`.

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
return $router->app->version();
});
$router->get('/cors', 'CorsController@index');
```

When I send the request with postman it is okay, it adds headers to the response. However, but then any options request will get a 200 response and wont be redirected or anything.

Earlier I tried doing this in my middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

But this always threw a `MethodNotAllowedError`.

Also I use my request content when I create a new one.
My question is how to handle options requests with CORS in laravel correctly, that it would not throw error and I would not lose my request content?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->getMethod() == 'OPTIONS'){

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Authorization');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        exit(0);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: That also return good response but it exits to a blank page, I am not sure if that is right though.

Comment: I just learned that it is pre-flight request so it should be that way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me the key to success was to add this nice route handling for OPTIONS.

Works on many of the latest Laravel versions since 7 (or older?)

```php
// routes/<name>.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

// Handle all routes to reply CORS headers
Route::options('{all}', [Controller::class, 'noContents'])->where('all', '.*');

Route::group(['prefix' => '/', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
    Route::get('/', [Controller::class, 'home']);
    Route::post('/version', [Controller::class, 'version']);
    Route::post('/register', [Controller::class, 'register']);
});
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function noContents(): Response
    {
        return new Response('', 204);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

final class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        self::setHeadersOnResponse($response->headers);
        return $response;
    }

    public static function setHeadersOnResponse(ResponseHeaderBag $responseHeaders): ResponseHeaderBag
    {
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type',
            'Authorization',
        ];
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');// This is a bit unsafe, use real values instead of "*"
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1000');
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', implode(',', $headers));
        return $responseHeaders;
    }
}
```

```php
// app/Http/Kernel.php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        // ...
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        // ...
    ];

    /**
     * The application's middleware aliases.
     *
     * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        // ...
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        // ...
    ];
}
```